# How to perform arithmetic on the result of Collectors.counting()?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, collectors

Given:

`List<Integer> myIntegers = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2);`

Return:

an Integer = Sum(((Frequency of Integer) / 2)))

I'm able to get the frequency of each integer using Collectors.groupingBy(), but want to then divide each frequency value by 2 and then sum all the values in the map, returning just an Integer:

`Map<Integer, Long> myIntegerMap = myIntegers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingby(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));`

`for(Map.Entry<Integer, Long> a : myIntegerMap.entrySet()){ System.out.print(a.getKey(), + "==>"); System.out.println(a.getValue());}`

Output:

1 ==> 2

2 ==> 2

3 ==> 1

4 ==> 1

Desired Output:

( ( 2 / 2 ) + ( 2 / 2 ) + ( 1 / 2 ) + ( 1 / 2 ) ) = 2

Comment: You have to start a new stream from the `:values()` of the map and operate on that.

Comment: There’s a wrong comma in your print statement. But why do you write `System.out.print(a.getKey() + "==>"); System.out.println(a.getValue());` anyway, instead of a straight-forward `System.out.println(a.getKey() + "==>" + a.getValue());`? Besides that, I don’t understand the purpose of your code. Your repeated integer division piles up rounding errors. Without those rounding errors, your final result would just be `myIntegers.size()/2`

Comment: Yes, typo in the print statement and can be simplified. The purpose of all this is to return the total number of pairs of integers in the list.

Comment: I see. So the rounding error equals to the number of odd counts, which is the number of non-paired elements. Makes sense. The alternative would be to only count the number of odd frequencies and subtract it from the list size (before halving), `Map<Integer, Boolean> oddValues = myIntegers.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> true, (a,b) -> a ^ b));  long result = (myIntegers.size() - Collections.frequency(oddValues.values(), true)) / 2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use two statements.  You can do it in the same construct as doing the frequency count.

First compute the frequencies and then use `CollectingAndThen` to post process the map and add up the values after dividing by `2` to get the desired result.

```
long result = myIntegers.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
         Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                 Collectors.counting()),
           mp -> mp.values().stream().mapToLong(a->a/2).sum()))

System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a map-reduce approach like so:

```
  long result = myIntegerMap.values().stream()
            .mapToLong(aLong -> aLong / 2)
            .sum();
```

Hope I didn't misunderstand your question and this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8 you can do this way:

```java
int result = myIntegerMap.entrySet().stream()
                .mapToInt(entry -> (int) (entry.getValue() / 2))
                .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> myIntegers = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2);
    Map<Integer, Long> myIntegerMap = myIntegers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    // get the value field from the map and create another stream to calc the result
    long sum = myIntegerMap.values().stream().map(v -> v/2).mapToLong(i -> i).sum();
```

Comment: you can eliminate the `mapToLong(i->i)` by just doing `mapToLong(v->v/2)`.

Comment: you are right. That is more simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Long findSum(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()),map -> map.entrySet().stream().map(data -> data.getValue() / 2).mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum()));           
    }
```